# Extract years from panel data and portfolio construction

Tags: r, sorting, extract, panel-data

I have a panel data set with return, ESG score and market value for a number of companies over 11 years. I need to extract data for all variables for one year at a time, to make yearly portfolios.

[The data frame looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFX99.png)

How can I extract one year at a time and then construct portfolios of high and low ESG score for each year?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try to improve your question, so we can help with the problem you're having (at the moment your question matches what we consider a "low quality question"). To improve it, edit it and add: 1. some sample of your data. The results of `dput(head(myData))` can do it. 2. show us what you've tried. SO is aimed at _helping you solve your problems_, not actually solving them. And 3. What errors or unexpected / undesired behaviors you've encountered in your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered processing the data with Python and Pandas instead of R? The following solution should help to slice your data into different time intervals:

[Slice JSON File into Different Time Intercepts with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620061/slice-json-file-into-different-time-intercepts-with-python)

In terms of sorting ESG scores, you can use the following command: `df.sort_values('ESG')`

Hope that helps and good luck with your dataset.